# WCF services stop working in IIS6

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I have a Windows 2003 SP2 server, and I have an ASP.NET web application published on it's IIS6.
That web application consumes a bunch of WCF services published in the same server.
The application is running OK, but a couple of times in the day I have to use the "iisreset /restart" command because the app stops working, and the users get this message:

> El cliente encontró el tipo de contenido de respuesta '', pero se esperaba 'text/xml'.
>   Error de la solicitud con una respuesta vacía.

I've detected that the services are failing, but when I restart the service they work again.
I am looking at the event viewer and I get an error:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/39277698
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: El servicio >'/saceserv/GuiaMadreService/GuiaMadre.svc' no se puede activar debido a una excepción >producida durante la compilación. El mensaje de excepción es: No se puede encontrar el >punto de entrada denominado 'FreeCredentialsHandle' en el archivo DLL 'security.Dll'.. ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: No se puede encontrar el punto de entrada denominado >'FreeCredentialsHandle' en el archivo DLL 'security.Dll'.

I hope you can help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: From translate.google.com:  Client found response content type of'', but expected 'text / xml'. The request failed with an empty response.

Comment: Second message: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment + HostingManager/39277698 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: Service> '/ saceserv / GuiaMadreService / GuiaMadre.svc' can not be activated due to an exception> during compilation. The exception message is: Could not find the> entry point named 'FreeCredentialsHandle' in DLL 'security.dll' .. ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Can not find entry point named> 'FreeCredentialsHandle' in DLL 'security.dll'.

Answer (score 0):

You must close 'WCF ServiceClients', with `Close()` method.